# Set Current Location for searchinng Nearby Hospital to the user

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am using bing maps for Windows Phone app, On one Button Tap I want to show all the nearby Hospitals to me, I implemented but it not shows the my nearby hospitals.

```
private void Nearest_Hospital_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();
mapsTask.SearchTerm = "hospital";
mapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;
mapsTask.Show();
}
```

I want to send the User's Current Location to this so that app will help the user to find the Hospitals nearby to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the users location using the GeoLocation API in Windows Phone. You can then use these coordinates to set the center value of the MapTask.

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the user's current location, use this as the center value of the MapTask.

```
Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
var lat = myGeoposition.Coordinate.Latitude;
var long = myGeoposition.Coordinate.Longitude;
```